# How to weight a TermDocumentMatrix by document length?

Tags: r, tm

I'm doing some text mining in `R` using the `tm` package. I'm familiar with `weightTfIdf` as a weighting option:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = list(dictionary = c("argument"), weighting = weightTfIdf))
```

However, all the documents I deal with do contain the term I'm looking for, but only to different degrees - therefore TfIdf does not work. How can I weight the `TermDocumentMatrix` by length of documents?

Comment: I would like to know this as well!

Comment: @spindoctor: upvoting the question would help then...